# Problems understanding a specific Prolog recursive predicate

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm in the process of learning Prolog.
I have this recursive predicate:

> add(0,Y,Y).
>   add(succ(X),Y,succ(Z)) :-
>   add(X,Y,Z).

Alright, so experienced Prolog programmers will probably understand what this predicate does. At first sight it doesn't look too hard to understand; when given two numerals as the first and second argument, it will return the result of adding them up as its third argument. Sounds simple? Indeed.

But I have a major problem comprehending how this actually works. I've re-read the description of this predicate many times but yet I am not able to understand how it actually works. And that's why I'm asking for help.

By querying this:
`add(succ(succ(succ(0))), succ(succ(0)), R).`
Prolog will instantiate and thus return `R` as `succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(0)))))`. Fine. This must be correct. However I have no clue why it is so.

What I have problems understanding is *how* and *why* Prolog strips off the outermost `succ` functor from the original query. Again, as it is recursive, it passes on the results as arguments onto itself, and thus stripping off the  outermost `succ` functor until the goal can be unified. I do understand how the `succ(Z)` and the argument `R` works, but I am seemingly unable to comprehend how it actually strips off the outermost `succ` functor, as mentioned. For me, it seems like it's *adding* a `succ` instead of stripping it, because of `succ(X)` in the predicate definition.

Any help is **greatly appreciated**. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prolog sees the line `add(succ(X),Y,succ(Z)) ...` and thinks "oh, it can be matched to the query `add(succ(succ(succ(0))), succ(succ(0)), R).`, because I can set (unify) X=succ(succ(0)), Y=succ(succ(0)), succ(Z)=R !" The important condition for Prolog, the one that determines it *can do it* is that `succ(succ(succ(0)))` can be matched to `succ(X)`, the rest is just simple, because Y and R can be in this first step set arbitrarily (they are not unified yet). And `succ(succ(succ(0)))` can be matched to `succ(X)` just because succ(A) can be matched to succ(B) any time A can be matched to B - you see it is not very hard for computer to decide it.

The next step is that Prolog looks at the rest of the line (:- `add(X,Y,Z)`) and generate query `add(succ(succ(0)), succ(succ(0)), Z)`. Remember that succ(Z)=R and it won't change until (if) the computation path is rejected. The next query will be `add(succ(0), succ(succ(0)), Z')`, where succ(Z')=Z. Then `add(0, succ(succ(0)), Z'')`, where succ(Z'')=Z'.

Then can Prolog use the first rule, determine that `Z''=Y=succ(succ(0))`. Then there is nothing left to do, so it just write to the output that `R=succ(Z)=succ(succ(Z'))=succ(succ(succ(Y)))=succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(0)))))`.

Comment: Wonderful explanation! Thank you very much. Accepted answer.